# Pass var to php via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass values to php file. I am getting alert that The form was submitted but Nothing is displaying in php file. I checked the js variables and they are displaying correctly. This is my HTML form.

```
                         <form name="sentMessage"role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="ContactForm" onsubmit="myFunction()">
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z ]{1,}$" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name" id="Username"
                                    data-error="Plese enter your name" required>
                                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" name="email" id="Useremail" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <input type="tel" pattern="^[_0-9 ]{1,}$" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" name="phone" id="Userphone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" name="message" id="Usermesage" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>

                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    <label class="light">
                                </div>


                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl btn-success">
                                    Send Message
                                </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>

 <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var name = document.getElementById("Username").value;
                var email = document.getElementById("Useremail").value;
                var phone = document.getElementById("Userphone").value;
                var message = document.getElementById("Usermesage").value;

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'mailer.php',
                  data: {'name': name, 'email':email,'phone':phone,'message':message},
                  success: function(){
                  alert("The form was submitted");
                }
                });


            }
    </script>
```

PHP file mailer.php

```
<?php
if($_POST){
echo $name = $_POST['name'];
echo $email = $_POST['email'];
echo $phone = $_POST['phone'];
echo $message = $_POST['message'];


}

?>
```

Nothing is displaying in php file. Thank you

Comment: Debug $_POST and check if there is any data submitted.

Comment: try adding `var_dump($_POST);` on the first line of mailer.php. Also can you show the html for the form fields?

Comment: its displaying array(0) { }

Comment: Show the HTML for your form

Comment: When you use AJAX, the output isn't displayed automatically. It's returned as the argument to the `success:` function, and that function needs to display it.

Comment: You will never see the output of your `mailer.php` file when using ajax.

Comment: @GaryJohnson he can see the output of `mailer.php` by inspecting the network tab and viewing the preview of the result from the ajax call...

Comment: I edit my html form for those who wanted to see it.

Comment: yes - it is the double form submission that is the issue - this button (<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl btn-success">)  is a submit button inside the form and will trigger the submission of  the form (irrespective of hte onsubmit function you have on the form) and then there will be no values for your ajax call. You need to prevent the normal form submssion so that your function can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts - are you submitting the form via normal form submit and then trying to submit the same form via the AJAX call. This would give no values to the AJAX call because they have already been submitted - you may need to prevent the normal form submission - there are plenty of answers in here related to that which will help you prevent the form submitting until the AJAX function.

Second - I would go so far as to remove the submit button from inside the form, give it a type = "button" attribute and combine the onclick event handler and ajax call (note that I am using the serialize() method to gather all the relevant data from the form without specifically getting each inputs' value and am :-

```
//html
    <button id="submitFormButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

//js
$('#submitFormButton').click(function(){
    var formData = $('#contactForm').serialize();
    var URL = 'mailer.php';
      $.post(URL, formData,function( data ) {
       //function to perfrom on the returned data
      });
 });
```

Comment: you do know that `echo $name = $_POST['name'];` is perfectly valid syntax.     The assignment expression still happens on the rhs and then the resulting expression is echoed, you can then still do `echo $name` afterward if you want to.

Comment: Thanks @Alex - I did not realise that - will amend my answer - thanks.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to point that out before people think it really is invalid syntax :)